# Why is array initialization slowing down multithreading?

Tags: c#, arrays, multithreading, unity-game-engine, hash

I'm trying to add threading support to a method that hashes coordinates in multiple dimensions. The long term goal here is to include the `FNV1A` hash, but the slowdown appears as soon as simply initializing the coordinate array in the `Hash` method.

I iterate a million times, and for 1 thread I get stopwatch times of ~300ms. For 8 threads that time bumps to ~6000ms.

Is this a false sharing issue? If so, my concern is that the hash will deteriorate with padding and offsets injected into the array. Any help on getting this to perform using local arrays would be greatly appreciated. Thanks much!

```
public class Foo : MonoBehaviour {
    #region Fields
    private readonly int iterations = 1000000;
    private readonly int threadNum = 1;
    private int iterationsCompleted = 0;
    #endregion

    void Start () {
        Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();
        Multithread();
        stopWatch.Stop();
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log(stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
    }

    private void Multithread() {
        for (int i = 0; i < threadNum; i++) {
            Hash hash = new Hash();
            new Thread(() => {
                while (Interlocked.Increment(ref iterationsCompleted) < iterations) {
                    hash.Get(0, 0, 0);
                }
                UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Finished thread");
            }).Start();
        }
        while (iterationsCompleted < iterations);
    }
}

public class Hash {
    #region Fields
    // FNV parameters can be found at http://www.isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/fnv/#FNV-param
    private const uint _FNVPrime = 16777619;
    private const uint _FNVOffset = 2166136261;
    private const uint _FNVMask8 = (1<<8)-1;
    #endregion

    #region Class Methods
    private static uint FNV1A(uint[] data) {
        uint hash = _FNVOffset;
        int dataSize = data.Length * sizeof(UInt32);
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[dataSize];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(data, 0, byteArray, 0, dataSize);
        for (int i = 0; i < dataSize; i++) {
            hash = hash ^ byteArray[i];
            hash = hash * _FNVPrime;
        }
        return hash;
    }

    public uint Get(int x, int y, uint seed) {
        uint[] data = new uint[3] { (uint)x, (uint)y, seed };
        //return FNV1A(data);
        return 0;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure about this because I didn't use threads in unity yet, but I think MonoBehaviour derived classes will have a problem with multithreading (at least functions that are inherited from it).

Comment: It must be the overhead of allocating a new array. You have two options: use FNV1A with a fixed amount of ints instead of an array, or preallocate a single array, one per thread.

Comment: @TamasHegedus it may be helpful to note that for a million iterations and 1 thread I was getting stopwatch times close to ~300ms. Bumping to 8 pushed the time to ~6000ms. That doesn't seem like array overhead. I will add that info to the post also.

Comment: @RichardHorne I think I found the problem. Update your complete code so that I can test it.

Comment: What are the values of `threadNum`,`iterationsCompleted` and `iterations`?

Comment: @Programmer updated

Comment: I optimized it a little bit and performance improved alot. Before I post it,  Is your test result with `return FNV1A(data);` commented out?

Comment: @Programmer sorry, I read that wrong. Yes, the test does have the commented out portion.

Comment: @Programmer out of curiosity, did the performance gains you saw on your end result in expected gains due to multithreading? Please share your solution if you have one. Thanks!

Comment: @RichardHorne Take a look at my answer. Let me know if you have any question.

Comment: It seems that you are likely beating up on a global heap that isn't tuned for multi-threaded access so there's a lot of contention for what is essentially several threads doing nothing but allocating (then dropping) small memory allocations.  I don't know much about the .NET runtime internals anymore, but this might be influenced by running under a debugger (if that's what you're doing).  See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6251689/12711 - a server configuration of the heap, which has a per-CPU heap, might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memory allocation seems to be the issue here. I made both arrays `static` then allocated memory outside of the functions once.I `locked` both array each time they are accessed to make sure that another `Thread` is not accessing them. Not sure how safe my code even after using the `lock` keyword.

**None related problem**:

`while (iterationsCompleted < iterations);` is called on the main `Thread`. This is not good and can will freeze Unity temporary each time `Multithread()` is called and still running. I added another `Thread` on top of that that will start `whenMultithread()` is called. So other Threads are now being called from this new `Thread` instead of the main `Thread`.

**Test Results On My Computer**

*Original Code*:

```
1 thread = 454.3515
8 threads = 655.008
```

*Modified Code*:

```
1 thread = 296.794
8 threads = 107.8898
```

Performance for `8` threads improved more than `6x`.
All tests were done with `return FNV1A(data);` included in the code and `return 0;` removed/commented from the code.

Now, your job is to make sure that the data/hash you are getting is what you expect.

```
public class Foo : MonoBehaviour
{
    #region Fields
    private readonly int iterations = 1000000;
    private readonly int threadNum = 1;
    private int iterationsCompleted = 0;
    #endregion

    void Start()
    {
        Multithread();
    }

    private void Multithread()
    {
        Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();

        //Start new Thread so that while (iterationsCompleted < iterations) ; will not run in the main loop
        new Thread(() =>
          {

              for (int i = 0; i < threadNum; i++)
              {
                  Hash hash = new Hash();
                  new Thread(() =>
                  {
                      while (Interlocked.Increment(ref iterationsCompleted) < iterations)
                      {
                          hash.Get(0, 0, 0);
                      }
                      UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Finished thread");
                  }).Start();
              }
              while (iterationsCompleted < iterations) ;
              stopWatch.Stop();
              UnityEngine.Debug.Log(stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);

          }).Start();
    }
}

public class Hash
{
    #region Fields
    // FNV parameters can be found at http://www.isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/fnv/#FNV-param
    private const uint _FNVPrime = 16777619;
    private const uint _FNVOffset = 2166136261;
    private const uint _FNVMask8 = (1 << 8) - 1;
    private const int FIXEDSIZE = 3;
    private readonly System.Object locker = new System.Object();
    #endregion

    #region Class Methods
    private static uint FNV1A(uint[] data)
    {
        uint hash = _FNVOffset;

        Buffer.BlockCopy(data, 0, byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

        for (int i = 0; i < byteArray.Length; i++)
        {
            hash = hash ^ byteArray[i];
            hash = hash * _FNVPrime;
        }
        return hash;
    }

    static byte[] byteArray = new byte[FIXEDSIZE * sizeof(UInt32)];
    static uint[] data = new uint[3] { (uint)0, (uint)0, 0 };

    public uint Get(int x, int y, uint seed)
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            data[0] = (uint)x;
            data[1] = (uint)y;
            data[2] = (uint)seed;
            return FNV1A(data);
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```